# How can I make "isinstance" on Protocols also include function signatures and data-types?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

The following code defines a simple protocol and a class which *almost* implements that protocol. The only difference is the fact that the `run()` method takes an argument in the protocol, but it's not implemented that way.

However, the `isinstance()` check returns true which was unexpected.

As I understood [PEP-544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) this *should* work. Although it's pretty unclear about checking function signatures.

The same issue happens when using the wrong data-type in the `ORDER` member (f.ex. changing it to `str` in the protocol).

I'm aware that type-hints are just... well... "hints" and are not enforced at runtime.

However, in my application it would be useful to ensure certain classes follow a defined protocol for clearer error-messages. It is using a plugin-architecture, and after loading a plugin it would be useful to have a quick "sanity-check" if that plugin follows the required protocol and if not, give an early and useful error-message instead of causing an exception later on downstream.

```py
from typing_extensions import Protocol, runtime_checkable


@runtime_checkable
class PFoo(Protocol):
    ORDER: int

    def run(self, a: int) -> None:
        ...


class Hello:
    ORDER = 10

    def run(self) -> None:
        print(1)


# Returns "True" evn though the signature of "run()" doesn't match
print(isinstance(Hello(), PFoo))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the docstring for the `runtime_checkable` function in the `typing` [module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/typing.py):

```
"""Mark a protocol class as a runtime protocol.

Such protocol can be used with isinstance() and issubclass().
Raise TypeError if applied to a non-protocol class.
This allows a simple-minded structural check very similar to
one trick ponies in collections.abc such as Iterable.
For example::

    @runtime_checkable
    class Closable(Protocol):
        def close(self): ...

    assert isinstance(open('/some/file'), Closable)

Warning: this will check only the presence of the required methods,
not their type signatures!
"""
```

If you want to compare type-annotations of functions, you can  examine the `__annotations__` attribute of the function (if it's a module that has `from __future__ import annotations` enabled,  it may be better to use [`typing.get_type_hints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#introspection-helpers) on the function rather than examining the `__annotations__` attribute directly). And if you're looking for an *exact* signature match, you can use the `signature` function from the `inspect` module — docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html). Beware: I think using `inspect.signature` may incur some runtime performance costs (but then again, so does all runtime type-checking).

Comment: Thanks. I did not think of the inspect module. This might indeed do the trick. And I'm not too worried about the impact it will have as this will only be a one-time startup check to load plugins. I must have missed the warning in the docstring when perusing the docs :| Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that a given concrete class satisfies these constraints (method names along with their parameters) I think would be better served by the `abc` module:

```py
import abc

class AFoo(abc.ABC):
    ORDER: int

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def run(self, a: int) -> None:
        raise NotImplemented


class Foo(AFoo):
    ORDER = 10

    def run(self) -> None: # The missing 'a' argument should be found offending by your static analyzer
        print(1)


foo = Foo()
print(isinstance(foo, AFoo))
```

Note however that defining a method that has the same name but not the same argument names or argument types as the base abstract class would still not be caught by the `isinstance()` call. I think in Python the subclassing rules are not sensitive to such differences.